# Wordpress post loop have posts fatal error?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, wordpress

I made a custom post loop query based on data from another plugin.

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object
```

Here is the code I have made:

Comment: I think it's because your query is wrong.

Comment: please make sure that you enter code into your question with the code sample button in the toolbar.  it is not showing up in your post

Answer (score 0):

You assign the select to `$most_viewed` var, but then you want to pass `$sql` variable. In the beginning, change `$most_viewed =`  to `$sql = ...`